# How Can I Stop a List, in Edit Mode, from Scrolling When Selecting or Leaving a Multi-Line Text Field?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

I would like to turn this behavior off; any ideas on how to stop this?  I don't want SharePoint's help moving the display; my users will scroll to where it is most useful.

Issue:
When selecting or leaving a note field, the s4-workspace div, scrolls horizontally in bizarre ways.  This makes it difficult for my uses to keep track of what item they are working on.

In Edit/Grid mode:

- When selecting then note field, it always moves the field 10-20px outside of the browser.
- After editing the note field and selecting another field, the new field is moved 10-20px outside of the browser.

Setup:

25 fields are displayed; I think the important part is that only 7-10 columns can appear at once in the browser, so more than half the fields are scrolled off screen at any given time.

- Single line text
- Date
- Choice

The field that is causing problems is:

- Multiple lines of Text
- Number of lines for editing = 6
- Enhanced rich text

This field is the last displayed in the View.

Comment: See if you changed the overflow of s4-workspace to hidden: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9422aa0f-5010-4691-a0ab-25e7aca6b478/issue-with-div-s4workspace-and-scroll-bar?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious